# How to slice Kinetics400 training dataset? (pytorch)

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to run the official [script](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/references/video_classification/train.py) for video classification.
I want to tweak some functions and running through all examples would cost me too much time.
I wonder how can I slice the training kinetics dataset based on that script.
This is the code I added before
`train_sampler = RandomClipSampler(dataset.video_clips, args.clips_per_video)`
in the script: (let's say I just want to run 100 examples.)

```
tr_split_len = 100
dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [tr_split_len, len(dataset)-tr_split_len])[0]
```

Then when hitting `train_sampler = RandomClipSampler(dataset.video_clips, args.clips_per_video)`
, it pops out the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Subset' object has no attribute 'video_clips'
```

Yeah, so the type of `dataset` converts from `torchvision.datasets.kinetics.Kinetics400` to `torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset`.
I understand. So how can I do it? (hopefully not the way using `break` in the dataloader loop).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `torchvision.datasets.kinetics.Kinetics400` internally uses an object of class [`VideoClips`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/e61747438522e2d5a92b0b7836754be1a7eb9017/torchvision/datasets/video_utils.py#L75) to store the information about the clips. It is stored in the member variable `Kinetics4000().video_clips`.

The `VideoClips` class has a function called [`subset`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/e61747438522e2d5a92b0b7836754be1a7eb9017/torchvision/datasets/video_utils.py#L176), that takes a list of indices and returns a new `VideoClips` object with only the clips with the specified indices. You could then just replace the old `VideoClips` object with the new one in your dataset.